# Почему наречие "заполночь" часто пишут раздельно?

Tags: орфография

В словаре в настоящее время дается слитное написание: **полночь ― заполночь**, в зн. нареч. Очень поздно.

Но чем объяснить, что в **Нацкорпусе намного чаще встречается написание раздельное, частотность 1000:80?** (И орфографический редактор подчеркивает слитную форму).

Слитное написание наречия **"зАполночь"** понятно, так как оно противопоставлено раздельному написанию словосочетания с падежным управлением **"зА полночь"**, вот только ударение в нем также на предлоге: "**ЗА полночь перевалило,** завтрашний день начинался, а никаких немцев не было и в помине. [Борис Васильев. А зори здесь тихие (1969)]

**Примеры:**

И **за полночь** мы, перебивая друг друга, придумывали все новые и новые повороты сюжета. [Дина Рубина. Окна (2011)].

**Уже заполночь** Захар с Андрюшей вышли от Минчиных, и выяснилось, что к вечеру страшно похолодало. [Дина Рубина. Белая голубка Кордовы (2008-2009)]

Comment: _**Sibylla**: В словаре в настоящее время дается слитное написание: **полночь ― заполночь**, в зн. нареч_. === Нет, не так. У Кузнецова не тире, а дефис: _**полночь-заполночь**_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Розенталя пока не отменили - *за полночь* пишется в два слова.

Вот на что могут опираться те, кто пишет слитно:

> Орфографические изменения, предлагаемые в проекте "Свода правил
>   русского правописания. Орфография. Пунктуация", от которых
>   Орфографическая комиссия решила отказаться на 01.10.2001
>
> <...>
>
> 4) § 83, п. 6. Заменить слитным раздельное написание следующих
>   наречий: всердцах, дозарезу, доупаду, заполдень, заполночь, навесу,
>   наощупь, наплаву, наскаку, насносях, подстать, а также непрочь.
>
> Процесс кодификации слитных написании наречий традиционно носит сугубо
>   индивидуальный характер, т. е. направлен на конкретные языковые
>   единицы. Выборочный подход к закреплению слитных написаний наречий
>   обусловлен, с одной стороны, устойчивостью традиций письма, а с
>   другой, живым характером процесса обособления наречий от парадигмы
>   существительных и вытекающей отсюда возможностью различной
>   лингвистической интерпретации одного и того же факта.

[**источник**](http://www.tetran.ru/SiteContent/Details/85)

Для нас ориентир - [**§58. Раздельное написание наречных сочетаний**](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/35.htm#):

> **3. Пишутся раздельно употребленные в наречном значении сочетания имен существительных с предлогами:**
>
> *без,* например: *без ведома, без запроса, без обиняков, без оглядки, без отказа, без просвета, без просыпу, без разбору, без спросу, без
>   толку, без удержу, без умолку, без устали;*
>
> *в,* например: *в дым, в лоск, в стельку* (пьяный), *в подбор, в придачу, в складчину, в старину, в стык, в тупик, в тупике;*
>
> *до,* например: *до зарезу, до отвала, до отказа, до смерти, до упаду;*
>
> *за*, например: ***за полночь***;
>
> *на,* например: *на бегу, на весу, на виду, на лету, на скаку, на ходу; на вес, на вид, на вкус, на глаз, на глазок, на грех, на диво,
>   на зависть, на ощупь, на редкость, на славу, на смех;*
>
> *от,* например: *от силы* (три килограмма и т.п.);
>
> *по,* например: *по старинке;*
>
> *под,* например: *под стать, под уклон, под хмельком, под шумок;*
>
> *с,* например: *с ведома, с кондачка, с маху, с наскока, с панталыку (сбиться), с разбегу, с разгона, с размаху, с ходу.*
>
> То же при предлогах *в* и *на* с существительными во множественном
>   числе, например: *в головах, в ногах, на днях, на радостях, на рысях,
>   на сносях, на часах* (стоять).
>
> Пишутся раздельно выступающие в функции наречий сочетания предлога
>   *на* с неизменяемыми частями речи (частицами, междометиями): *на авось, на нет* (свести на нет), *на ура, на фуфу;* ср. также: *на
>   арапа, на шарап* и др.

Comment: Галина, а Ушаков?! ЗАПОЛНОЧЬ — нареч. (разг.). После полуночи. Мы засиделись заполночь.     Получается, что  Розенталь "исправил" Ушакова.  Далее: 1) Большой толковый словарь на Грамоте.ру:  Полночь-заполночь, в зн. нареч. Очень поздно. 2) Резниченко, словарь ударений (2010) - зАполночь (наречие), неправ. запОлночь. 3) Там же: Полночь - зА полночь (после 12 часов). 3) вышли (когда?) заполночь - перевалило (за что) за полночь, классический парный вариант.

Comment: 4) Сегодня на "Большом вопросе":За полночь или заполночь? Как правильно пишется? Какое правило? - Заполночь, наречие. Обозначает ночью, после полуночи. 5) Учительница русского выделила мне как ошибку в диктанте, т. к. я написала раздельно, а потом нашла это слово в словаре, а там оно было написано раздельно. ПОДСКАЖИТЕ, КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО?   6) Итак,  вопрос остается открытым, один Розенталь не справится с решением.

Comment: Сиби, не нашла такого вопроса на БВ. И важно, кто отвечает. Там два настоящих филолога - Светлана Кузнецова и Ирина Робертовна...

Comment: И не один Розенталь ратует за написание в два слова; "полночь-заполночь" - это понятно; у Ушакова очень много ошибок с позиций современного языка (одно "придти" дорогого стоит), а Резниченко - не имя. Другие словари пишут по Розенталю.

Comment: Да, придется остановится на раздельном написании наречного выражения,  так как во всех случаях это просто УКАЗАНИЕ НА ВРЕМЯ.  Дело в том, что и парного варианта нет: за полночь, но: успеть сделать за полночи, например: "Да я не за две, а за одну такую ночь, за полночи ...всех бы  их послала" (Василий Аксенов).

Comment: _**Sibylla**: 2) Резниченко, словарь ударений (2010) - зАполночь (наречие), неправ. запОлночь_. === Sibylla, я просмотрел несколько бумажных изданий "Словаря ударений русского языка" Резниченко, но ни в одном из них вот этого  "зАполночь (наречие), неправ. запОлночь" не обнаружил. Есть только **за полночь** в статье **полночь**. Вы смотрели бумажный словарь или же какую-то интернет-версию?

Answer (score 6):

> Почему наречие “заполночь” часто пишут раздельно?

Потому что именно такое его написание поддерживалось всеми словарями и справочниками в течение нескольких десятилетий после принятия **"Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"**, вышедших в 1956 году.

Так оно писалось в словаре ―  приложении к **Правилам-56**:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое же его написание фиксировалось и в выходивших в 50-ые годы справочниках для работников печати К.И. Былинским и Н.Н. Никольским, и в орфографических словарях, выходивших под редакцией С.Г. Бархударова, С.И. Ожегова, А.Б. Шапиро.

Чуть позднее ―   в 1967 году ―   появилось оно и у Розенталя в "Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке"...

Придерживались в 1987 году раздельного написания ***за полночь*** и авторы словаря "Слитно или раздельно?" (6-е изд.) Б.З. Букчина и Л.П. Калакуцкая.

**Сохранено раздельное написание этого наречия и в выходящем с 1999 года "Русском орфографическом словаре"** (т. наз. *лопатинском*).

И возможно,  сейчас бы не возникал вопрос о слитном/раздельном написании ***за/полночь***,  если бы не…

В 1998 году (видимо, на волне обсуждений в Орфографической комиссии  написания ряда слов) Б.З. Букчиной и Л.П. Калакуцкой в переработанном словаре "Слитно или раздельно?" раздельное написание наречия ***за полночь*** было заменено на слитное: ***заполночь***.

Впоследствии в словаре "Слитно? Раздельно? Через дефис?" (2013 г.) Букчина вернулась к раздельному написанию этого наречия.

**НО!..**

Слитное написание ***заполночь*** имело место ещё  в одном  выпущенном Букчиной (в соавторстве с И.К.Сазоновой и Л.К. Чельцовой)  словаре ―  в **"Орфографическом словаре русского языка"**.  Словарь этот интересен тем, что приказом Министерства образования и науки РФ № 195 от 08.06.2009 он **"включён в список грамматик, словарей и справочников, содержащих нормы современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации"**.

**"Орфографический словарь русского языка"**  после включения его в список *нормативных* дважды (по-моему!) переиздавался (последний раз   ―  в этом году), но изменениям при переизданиях вроде бы не подвергался.

**Вот что в нём сейчас (6-е изд., 2016):**

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3):

С наречиями всегда было сложно. Это новая часть речи, её образование ещё продолжается. Раньше к вопросу подходили проще: можно вставить вопрос или определение, значит,пока  сущ. с предлогом, выполняющее роль наречия, и пишется раздельно, в словарь  не вносили, нельзя - слитно.

Со словом ЗАПОЛНОЧЬ/ЗА ПОЛНОЧЬ сразу не заладилось.Оно же разговорное, но использовалось часто, входило в норму. Одни словари зафиксировали слитное написание(когда? заполночь), другие раздельное(далеко за что? за полночь), и каждый считал себя правым, Ожегов вообще воздержался, показав только "полночь". Отсюда и в Нацкорпусе различные написания: кто считает наречием - пишет слитно, кто сущ. с предлогом - раздельно.

Потом в науке пришли к выводу, что пора так и говорить: наречие или наречное выражение, и внесли в словари наречные выражения на правах наречий, зафиксировали раздельное написание, оставив ПОЛНОЧЬ-ЗАПОЛНОЧЬ как традиционное написание фразеологизма на базе просторечного существительного заполночь("была уже заполночь", как "заграница"), а целиком фразеологизм в роли наречия.

Когда в 2000-х вносили поправки в орфографию, Лопатин попытался упростить написание наречий, предложил и наречные выражения писать слитно, раз выполняют роль наречий, но его не поддержали, утверждая, что в сознании русского человека полночь - существительное, как и ночь, день, полдень.Было как поздно? - далеко (за что?) за полночь. Так и оставили. А как в словаре Лопатина, так теперь и пишем и творчество не проявляем, за исключением поэтов и писателей, они имеют право на творчество и своё видение слова.

Comment: Однообразие - это, конечно, вещь хорошая, но, например,  в выражении " я приехал домой  за полночь" предлог ЗА не участвует в падежном управлении, а  в выражении "было далеко за полночь, перевалило за полночь" - участвует. В орфографии существует принцип парных вариантов вида "наудачу - на удачу". Да еще ударение на предлоге способствует слитному написанию (сравнить: дОверху и до вЕрха). И с традицией как-то не получается: слитно (Ушаков) - раздельно (Розенталь) - слитно (Лопатин) - раздельно (современный вариант).

Comment: Так что помучимся мы еще с этим словом, тем более слитный вариант уже разошелся по разным словарям (толковым, орфоэпическим).

Comment: И "приехал за полночь" можно объяснить, как и "приехал за полдень": приехал до полуночи - приехал за полночь, до полудня - за полдень. Это же прямые антонимы. Почему одно наречие, а другое существительное с предлогом?Никто ж "дополуночи" слитно не писал? А про традицию я говорила о просторечии, когда "заполночь" употребляют как существительное по примеру "поехал в заграницу".Вы не вчитались в смысл.

Comment: А насчёт "помучимся" - нам-то  не страшно, не накажут, а вот школьникам что делать: велено писать по Лопатину, а там разыскной, считаный, зарянка, деланый, а они учили по-другому, как исключения, и в учебниках так до сих пор, их никто не переписывал